# How do i pass a list in scrapy's itemloader?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having difficulty getting the image url. how can i get the image_url in itemloader? It works fine if I yield a dictionary with value as image_url (withoud ItemLoader).

```
def parse_property(self, response):   
    
    l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
    url=response.meta.get('URL')
    l.add_value('url', response.url)
    l.add_xpath('title', '//div[@class="property- 
                 title"]/h1/text()',MapCompose(str.strip, str.title))
    l.add_xpath('offering', '//span[@class="property-badge"]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('area', '//ul[@class="property-main-features"]/li[contains(text(), "Area")]/span/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('rooms', '//ul[@class="property-main-features"]/li[contains(text(), "Rooms")]/span/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('bed_room', '//ul[@class="property-main-features"]/li[contains(text(), "Bedroom")]/span/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('bath_room', '//ul[@class="property-main-features"]/li[contains(text(), "Bathroom")]/span/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    #l.add_value('description', '//div[@class="description-div"]/ul/li/text()')
    #l.add_value('description', '//div[@class="description-div"]/p/text()')
    #l.add_value('description', '//div[@class="description-div"]/descendant::*/text()')
    l.add_xpath('ground_floor', '//*/strong[contains(text(), "Ground Floor")]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('first_floor', '//*/strong[contains(text(), "1st Floor")]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('top_floor', '//*/strong[contains(text(), "Top Floor")]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('facing', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "Facing")]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('location', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "Location")]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('building_age', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "Building Age")]/span/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('parking', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "Parking")]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('floors', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "floors")]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    l.add_xpath('area1', '//div[@class="additional-details"]/p[contains(text(), "Area")]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
    images=response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-12"]/descendant::img/@src').extract()
    image=("https://www.epropertynepal.com" + image for image in images)
    images=[i.split('?')[0] for i in image]
    image_url=[x for x in images if 'original' in x]
    #l.add_value('image_url', self.image_url)
    l.add_xpath('price', '//div[@class="property-pricing"]/div[1]/text()')

    return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
images=[i.split('?')[0] for i in image]
image_url=[x for x in images if 'original' in x]

l.add_value('images', image_url)
```

This will work fine

Comment: but you can use item loaders in much better way you don't need to process item in your parse method it self. there is a better way to process your item in item loader.

Comment: Thank you.Apparent we cant do this:  l.add_value('image_url', image_url)  and also i am looking into cleaning up the mess with a class using MapCompose.

Comment: MapCompose is a inbuilt processor in scrapy which works as map function in python. you can refer to https://github.com/yashpokar/amazon-crawler

Comment: Thanks once again.Very useful.I will be referring to your code for my own project.

Comment: I have but since i have only started on stack. Without reputation upvote is only registered and not displayed publicly.